# How can I wrap this fabric around this seat frame?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

[image][image]I am creating a UH-60 passenger seat. The blockout is done and I am trying to now do the fabric part however I am having trouble wrapping the seat fabric around the metal frame. I have tried adding in a plane, solidifying it and then adding a shrinkwrap modifier however that does not achieve the effect I want. Also have tried giving the seat frame collision and then ruining a cloth sim on the subdivided plane but it does not wrap around like I want it to, Reference and model below [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just model the fabric like any other part of the mesh?

Comment: I need the fabric to wrap around certain parts of the mesh, I could do it manually by extruding and loop cuts but thats takes very long and is also very dirty.

Comment: How realistic does it need to be, how close are you rendering this part? The reference image is tiny, I don't see the fabric sagging anywhere, it just look like a plane so you wouldn't need to spend so much time with sim or anything complicated.

Comment: This model is to be used for a game asset ive finished and it needs to be as realistic as possible. At the moment it is just a blockout however the cloth part is infact a solid 3d object with a small thickness. Ive also uploaded a new ref for better understanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the design for these online, it seems that the seats connect to the frames, in a sort of cross shape with bevels.

What I think might produce a good result is copying and re using part of the metal frame mesh to start.[image]

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdsQW.jpg)

duplicate and separate these parts, taking care not to select one area you wish to bridge loop.

[image]

go into edit mode and create a plane in the middle that matches the edge loops.

[image]

Bridge the edge loops:
[image]

Shrink/fatten everything so it fits properly and add bevel, solidify and subdivide modifiers so that it looks better.  Duplicate the  created mesh for both parts of the seat if possible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Cant believe i didnt think of this and instead went for the stupid complex ways haha

Comment: One small question I do have though is, how did you get the rungs to wrap back around into the seat cloth in the last picture?

Comment: The bottom tabs are probably stitched together with the cloth, so we don't have to worry about bridging those.  I'll throw in one extra image to show that.

Comment: I mean moreso as to how you managed to get those in the first place, Ive added pictures of my mesh to show you what I mean otherwise it was a perfect solution and I cant thank you enough

Comment: Glad to help.  When you first select your rings, you want them to have gap , so that they are not O but C shaped.

Comment: Is it possible to get a little recording of that specific part if you have the time? Not sure why its confusing me so much haha